# php smarty calculate rates

Tags: php, smarty, pow

I have a formula i want to write in smarty. Because the formula have more than one pow(), it get tricky and does not seem to work anyhow.

This is the formula:

```
rate = Kapital*((Zinssatz_Effektiv/100+1)^(1/12))^Monate/((((Zinssatz_Effektiv/100+1)^(1/12))^Monate)-1)*(((Zinssatz_Effektiv/100+1)^(1/12))-1)
```

my try in smarty looks that way:

```
{math equation="x*((y/100+1)pow(1/12))pow z/((((y/100+1)pow(1/12))powz)-1)*(((y/100+1)pow(1/12))-1)" x=$Kapital y=$Zinssatz_Effektiv z=$Monate format="%.2f"}
```

Somehow the mixing with all pows is wrong and i dont get the clue how to make it.

Comment: For non Germans: Zinssatz = Fees; Monate = Months; Kapital = fund/capital;

Comment: And Zinssatz_Effektiv = actual Fees

Comment: Suggestion #1: move all the calculations in the `PHP` code, assign the computed values, format and display them in the templates. Suggestion #2 (if #1 is not good and you need the same formula again and again the many templates): write a smarty plugin that implements a template function. It's not difficult. Read the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) or check the source code of the functions bundled with Smarty.

Comment: I added an answer that implements suggestion #2. It is just a skeleton, you need to do proper parameter validation and implement the correct formula but you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the skeleton of a Smarty plugin you can implement to simplify the computations.

#### The implementation

Write the following function in a file you include in all pages:

```
function smarty_function_rate($params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
    // Validate input parameters
    // ... verify here that all the parameters are provided, 
    // call $smarty->trigger_error() to report invalid or missing values

    // Example
    if (! isset($params['kapital']) || floatval($params['kapital']) < 0) {
        $smarty->trigger_error("Parameter 'kapital' is mission or it have an invalid value. A number greater than zero was expected.", E_USER_ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
 

    // Extract the values
    $kapital  = $params['kapital'];
    $zinssatz = $params['zinssatz']
    $monate   = $params['monate'];

    // Do the complex calculation here using $kapital, $zinssatz, $monate
    $rate = $kapital * 0.01;      // this is NOT the formula :-)
    // And return the value
    return $rate;
}
```

You can name it whatever you want, this is just an example.

#### The registration

In order to make Smarty aware of your new plugin you have to register it.
You can do this as soon as you instantiate the `Smarty` object or only in the pages that need it, as you prefer.

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'rate', 'smarty_function_rate');
```

Here, `function` is the plugin type (`template function`), don't mess with it, `rate` is the name of the function, how you will call it in the templates (like `{rate kapital=123}`, you can put other name if you prefer) and `smarty_function_rate` is the name of the function that implements the plugin, described above. If you use a different name for the function then change it also in the registration call.

**Note:** *Smarty 2 has different methods to register each type of plugin, and they had one parameter less (the plugin type, of course). The method for functions in Smarty 2 is `register_function()`.*

#### Usage:

You can use the new function `{rate}` in the templates similar with the functions bundled with `Smarty`, like `{math}` or `{assign}`:

```
{rate kapital=1000 zinssatz=5 monate=12}
```

On the runtime the `smarty_function_rate()` function will be invoked having the `kapital`, `zinssatz` and `monate` as keys in `$param` and the value it returns will replace the function call.

For formatting of the result you can either modify the code of the plugin to get an additional parameter `$format` and return the value as a formatted string or you can provide it another parameter `assign` containing the name of a `Smarty` variable where it will store the result or both (as `{math}` does).